# Compare two hours javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to compare different hours, how I can do it?

My problem is like this:

How do I say midnight and more than nine in the morning or 
hours like 01 ,02 ... are greater than 13, 14 ,15?

I did:

a = 09:00 and b = 00:00

```
    function hours(){
        if(b > a) {
            return true
        } 
    }
```

, but my function return false!

Any idea?

Comment: May be you can convert to minutes or seconds equivalent..That way its easier to compare.

Comment: if in the same day, hour 00:?? won't ge greater (which is later) than XX:?? where XX is in [01, 23]

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple the hour with 100 and add minutues than compare for 00 use 24. i.e
9:20 will become 9 * 100 + 20 = 920; 
0:20 -> 24 * 100 +  20 =2420;
Why downvoted ?